# Serialize coordinates to JSON from Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization, key

I have a game with an infinite world, so I render it using chunks. Those chunks are stored in a dict like this:

```py
chunks = {
    (0,0) : {
        'floor' : 'stuff', 
        'items' : {}
    },
    (1,0) : {
        'floor' : 'more stuff', 
        'items' : {}
    }
}
```

As you can see, the chunk's coordinates are stored as a tuple, wjich is quite handy, but this stops me from serializing the dict to a JSON file.

Is there any way I can keep the key of each chunk as a tuple (x, y) and dumping the dict in to JSON?

Comment: "coordinates of the chunk as the key in the dict " can you explain this

Comment: @komatiraju032 sorry, I'm spanish and my english is not the best. Each chunk is stored in the dict with its coordinates as the key. I want the key to be a tuple so I can use (x, y) in my code

Comment: Why JSON? Are you saving it or sending it to some other application (not written in python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is what you need here. You can read about the difference with JSON [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json). In your case that would give:

**Saving**

```py
with open('map.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(chunks, f)
```

**Loading**

```
with open('map.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    chunks = pickle.load(f)
```

Which gives you the exact same dictionary as you saved (in binary format). I think using JSON only makes sense if you plan on sharing it with another application, in particular with a non-python application:

> JSON is interoperable and widely used outside of the Python ecosystem, while pickle is Python-specific;

Answer (score 1):

Actually json required your keys to be in string. You can convert your keys in string and store it in json and when you need to take your values back than you can revert them back to the original shape. In the code below I tried my best to solve your problem

```
import json
chunks = {
          (0,0) : {
                   'floor' : 'stuff', 
                   'items' : {}
                  },
          (1,0) : {
                   'floor' : 'more stuff', 
                   'items' : {}
                  }
         }

# To store dict into json
chunks = {str(k): v for k,v in chunks.items()}
stored_in_json = json.dumps(chunks)

# Load json and revert it back to the orignal shape
chunks = {eval(k): v for k,v in json.loads(stored_in_json).items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two helper methods `create_json()` and `create_dict()`.

`create_json()` method store the dictionary in json file by converting the tuple keys to strings.

`create_dict()` method create the dictionary from the json file created with `create_json()` method.

```
import json

chunks = {
          (0,0) : {
                   'floor' : 'stuff', 
                   'items' : {}
                  },
          (1,0) : {
                   'floor' : 'more stuff', 
                   'items' : {}
                  }
         }

def create_json(data):
    with open('test.json', 'w') as fw:
        res = {str(k): v for k, v in data.items()}
        json.dump(res, fw)

def create_dcit(json_file):
    with open(json_file) as fp:
        data = json.loads(fp.read())
        return {eval(k): v for k, v in data.items()}

create_json(chunks)

y = create_dcit('test.json')
```